# How can I retrieve information from a selected cell and adjacent cells in the row?

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I want to populate an Outlook email with information from a row of cells after selecting one cell in the row. The information for each row is the following:

- Column A: Email
- Column B: Name
- Column C: Message

How do I reference the cells in column B and column C after first selecting an email address in column A.

```
Sub populateEmail()
Dim outApp, myItem, myAddress, bodyString, location
Set myAddress = Selection
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = outApp.CreateItem(0)


 'populate bodyString with information on selected row


With myItem
    .Subject = "subject"
    .To = myAddress
    .Body = bodyString
    .Display
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the selected cell is in column A (which I assume your macro is relying on based on your `Set myAddress = Selection`) then other columns can be easily referenced using the `Offset` property.

So column B could be referenced using `Selection.Offset(0, 1)`, and column C could be referenced using `Selection.Offset(0, 2)`.

You could therefore create a string for the body of your email using something like:

```
bodyString = "Dear " & Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value & "," & vbCrLf & _
             Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value
```